# How use the mean method on a pandas TimeSeries with Decimal type values?

Tags: python, decimal, dataframe, pandas

I need to store Python decimal type values in a pandas `TimeSeries`/`DataFrame` object. Pandas gives me an error when using the "groupby" and "mean" on the TimeSeries/DataFrame. The following code based on floats works well:

```
[0]: by = lambda x: lambda y: getattr(y, x)

[1]: rng = date_range('1/1/2000', periods=40, freq='4h')

[2]: rnd = np.random.randn(len(rng))

[3]: ts = TimeSeries(rnd, index=rng)

[4]: ts.groupby([by('year'), by('month'), by('day')]).mean()
2000  1  1    0.512422
         2    0.447235
         3    0.290151
         4   -0.227240
         5    0.078815
         6    0.396150
         7   -0.507316
```

But i get an error if do the same using decimal values instead of floats:

```
[5]: rnd = [Decimal(x) for x in rnd]       

[6]: ts = TimeSeries(rnd, index=rng, dtype=Decimal)

[7]: ts.groupby([by('year'), by('month'), by('day')]).mean()  #Crash!

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\TM\Documents\Python\tm.py", line 100, in <module>
print ts.groupby([by('year'), by('month'), by('day')]).mean()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 293, in mean
return self._cython_agg_general('mean')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 365, in _cython_agg_general
raise GroupByError('No numeric types to aggregate')
pandas.core.groupby.GroupByError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

The error message is "GroupByError('No numeric types to aggregate')". Is there any chance to use the standard aggregations like sum, mean, and quantileon on the TimeSeries or DataFrame containing Decimal values?

Why doens't it work and is there a chance to have an equally fast alternative if it is not possible?

EDIT: I just realized that most of the other functions (min, max, median, etc.) work fine but not the mean function that i desperately need :-(.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I also ran into that issue recently. I just ended up recasting the Decimal() values into floats and then creating the data frame with the float values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
ts.groupby([by('year'), by('month'), by('day')]).apply(np.mean)
```

Comment: @ThomasM too encourage users to help you, you should upvote answers (clicking on the up arrow above the number left of the answer). If an answer actually solved your problem, you should accept it, too. To accept a question, you have to click on the tick mark below the number.

Comment: Also, you don't really need the lambda here, just feeding `np.mean` would work too, but I left the lambda in to illustrate how you would solve this when more general functions that you want to apply aren't working in their default ways. The `.apply` function is very powerful in Pandas.